# Can't forward to jsp when handling an exception

Tags: java, jsp, exception, servlets

So i got this problem, i do a servlet project using tomcat and I got this class that should handle the exception that was thrown and then display the jsp with error status code.

```java
public class ErrorHandler extends HttpServlet {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ErrorHandler.class);

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Throwable throwable = (Throwable) req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
        Integer statusCode = (Integer) req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
        if (throwable != null) {
            LOGGER.fatal("Exception: " + throwable);
        }
        if (statusCode != null) {
            LOGGER.fatal("Error, status code: " + statusCode);
        }
        req.getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(req, resp);
    }
}
```

This handler is mapped in the web.xml this way.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ErrorHandler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/error</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
```

The question is, why do i keep getting default tomcat exception page, instead of mine. My logger works just fine, so it's clear, that after exception was happened, method doGet is called, but when it comes to request dispatcher, it just doesn't work. My jsp pages are placed in webapp folder, near WEB-INF.

Answer (score 0):

Because the request dispatcher for `error.jsp` is just a dispatcher. Java/tomat isn't going to realize that `error.jsp` means you intended for this to *be* the error handler. It's just a page, just like `foo.jsp`. So, that dispatcher picks up the call, so to speak, notices that the request involves an error state, and it, in turn, forwards the request to the error dispatcher.